# how to install facebook in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04

I have a problem. I do a lot of collaborative work at university, and the main method of communication (and most convenient) for students use is Facebook. I would love to integrate Facebook messages with Ubuntu.

I know this is almost possible with Pidgin, but this is only really for chat, it doesn't allow me to be offline or see offline messages. It also constantly tells me people are going on and offline as I basically have every person I've ever met on there, and most of they check Facebook on an hourly basis.

I've seen android apps which have this functionality, so there must be an API for it. Is there an Ubuntu app which handles this nicely?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Pidgin can do both the things: 1. save chats and lets you see them later even if you're offline, 2. disable the "someone is online/offline" notification.

Comment: There's an Android app for it, because Facebook published said app. Facebook is not interested in officially supporting generic Linux, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Messenger for Desktop](https://messengerfordesktop.com/) and [Trillian](https://www.trillian.im/get/linux/6.1/linux.html), which is a multi-messenger for Facebook, Google Hangouts and more.

Comment: Any of them lets you "*see offline messages*"?

Answer (score 0):

[Franz](https://meetfranz.com) is a messaging service for Ubuntu, and it supports almost all the main communication services such as Messenger, WhatsApp, Google Hangouts, etc.